Помогите исправить баг со слайдером для аудио-плеера
Делаю аудио-плеер. Использую слайдер для переключения времени. Вот в чем проблема: когда музыка на паузе, то все ок, но когда играет, то слайдер при использовании дергается.
HTML:
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="progress-slider slider">

CSS:
.slider {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    /* border: #222 2px solid; */
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}

JS:
function formatTime(timeInSeconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(timeInSeconds % 60);
    return `${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

function updateProgress(e) {
    const { duration, currentTime } = e.srcElement;
    const progressPercent = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
    // progressSlider.value = `${progressPercent}`;
    progressSlider.value = progressPercent;

    progressCurrent.innerHTML = formatTime(audio.currentTime);
    //progressEnd.innerHTML = formatTime(duration);
}

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);

function setProgress(e) {
    // const width = this.clientWidth;
    // const clickX = e.offsetX;
    const duration = audio.duration;

    // audio.currentTime = (clickX / width) * duration;
    const progressValue = progressSlider.value;
    audio.currentTime = (progressValue / 100) * duration;
}

// progressContainer.addEventListener('change', setProgress);
progressSlider.addEventListener('change', setProgress);



как именно дергается? выведи в лог значение progressPercent  и currentTime возможно проблема с округлениями в расчетах

Дергается в смысле когда двигаешь слайдер, то прогресс увеличивается-уменьшается сам по себе внешне и временами при нажатии ничего не происходит(если использовать тачпад, то наоборот, вообще не реагирует).

ну так правильно - у тебя же одновременно приходят события и от изменения и от проигрывания

Я понимаю, но как это исправить. Ведь бывает, что изменяешь, а ничего не происходит. Это и выглядит плохо, так еще и неудобно, про тачпады на ноутах вообще молчу.

а какое поведение ты ожидаешь? Что должно происходить пока ты тянешь ползунок и одновременно идет проигрывание?

Нормальное поведение как на условном YouTube Music. Просто можно ли это как-то исправить или нужно реализовать слайдер по другому?

опиши словами нормальное поведение и добавь это в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

В Вашей ситуации следует заменить событие change на input:
progressSlider.addEventListener('input', setProgress);

И всё станет работать чётко. Причина - событие change срабатывает только после потери элементом progressSlider фокуса, а до этого успевает сработать timeupdate. (ещё гуглите на тему чем отличается onchange от oninput)
